# How to run 'format document' on hundreds of files?

Tags: visual-studio

I have hundreds of `.cs` files. I would like to run Visual Studio's 'format document' on them all. Is there any faster way than doing them individually and by hand?

Ideally `devenv.exe -formatdocument *.cs` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If they're in the same solution and on VS2010 you could try this extension:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6b560a24-8184-402b-be58-12a73834b590